# Trying export email to sendgrid account using google apps script from google sheet)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sendgrid

I'm trying export email from google sheet to my Sendgrid account:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var API_KEY = "your api key";
  var url = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients=" + API_KEY;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var results = data.hits;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var header = ["Email"]
  var items = [header];

  results.forEach(function (result) {
      items.push([result.email]);
  });
  sheet.getRange(1,1,items.length,items[0].length).setValues(items);
}
```

To finish that script I'm only need to insert my Sendgrid API key, but it still not working...

Maybe I choosen wrong "var url =" link?

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#Add-Single-Recipient-POST

Comment: Welcome!
Please consider adding `sendgrid`, `google-apps-script`, `google-sheets` and/or any other appropriate tags to the question.
Thank you, and good luck!

Comment: Can you provide the detail of `but it still not working...`?

Comment: You code fetches data from sendgrid and pastes into the sheet - but according to your description you try to do the opposite. Can you specify please what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: You are right ziganotschka, I read a small part  of https://dev.to/sagunsh/connect-google-sheets-to-3rd-party-api-using-apps-script-46dj tutorial and I take that script, but when I finally read to the end of this tutorial I realize I need a opposite (I need to send emails from google sheet to the Sendgrid account)... Can you help me with that?